# Running the build of create-react-app on Android's Web View

Tags: android, reactjs, android-webview, create-react-app

I want to run the build of a create-react-app in Android's web-view. When I run a simple web app with JavaScript and CSS, it is running fine. But on trying to run a create-react-app I am ending up with an empty screen.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. I used the following command for create-react app:

   npm install -g create-react-app

   create-react-app my-app
2. I created the build file using:

   npm run build
3. I copied and pasted the build folder into my Android project structure under assets directory. 
   [The build files in my Android Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp9VL.png)
4. My Main Activity code:

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
       WebSettings webSettings = view.getSettings();
       webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/build/index.html");
   }
   ```

   }

I am ending up with a blank screen on running the android app. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add code with question

Comment: Provide the code that causes the issue

Comment: I have added code to the question and have detailed the steps I had taken. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Do you get any error's? So you yes please show them

Comment: I have the same problem...

Comment: Did you resolve it?  I have the same trouble! It's running fine with android 6 or higher. android 4.4,  4.3, 4.2, 4.1, 4.0 is not fine

Answer (score 4):

Fix these two issues

1. Make CRA to build relative path,

Open `package.json` of CRA project and add `"homepage": "."` next to `"version"` tag at the same level.

2. Use `HashRouter` in `react-router`.

`react-router` that is if u are using one and u should. We usually use `BrowserRouter`. `HashRouter` is pretty useless and adviced [not to use](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter). But this scenario is the best place to use `HashRouter`.

ps. if you want more explanation or example, post in comments and i'll edit and add those as well